Trying to make a health system in renpy which depends on other stats
so I am making a game where you have stats and said stats are connected in a way so health = resilience*25 and it works great until you increase the stat so if resilience = 1 and then I added 1 and it = 2 it would still equal 1x25 instead of 2x25. and I have spent over 2 hours trying to look up any solutions without any success and the reason I want to do this is so that I can add random stat gain after every encounter so that the health gets automatically set correctly based on the resilience stat, I thought the default function was the problem it might be but I don't know waht to change it to for this to work please help.
default strength = 1
default resilience = 1
default agility = 1
default health = resilience*25

any advise is helpful even if its to just scrap the idea and instead do something else to still have the same effect
